# Ruby file renamer

Tags: ruby, file

this is a text file renamer i made, you throw the file in a certain folder and the program renames them to file1.txt, file2.txt, etc

it gets the job done but it's got two problems

1. it gives me this error `no implicit conversion of nil into String error`
2. if i add new files into the folder where there's already organized files, they're all deleted and a new file is created

what's causing these problems?

```
i=0

Dir.chdir 'C:\Users\anon\Desktop\newfolder'
arr = Dir.entries('C:\Users\anon\Desktop\newfolder')

for i in 2..arr.count
if (File.basename(arr[i]) == 'file'+((i-1).to_s)+'.txt')
puts (arr[i]+' is already renamed to '+'file'+i.to_s)
else
File.rename(arr[i],'file'+((i-1).to_s)+'.txt')
end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two main problems in your program.

The first is that you are using an out of bounds value in the array `arr`. Try this `a = [1,2,3]; a[a.count]` and you will get `nil` because you are trying at access `a[3]` but the last element in the array has index 2.

Then, you are using as indexes for names `fileINDEX.txt` always `2...foobar` without taking into account that some indexes may be already used in your directory.

Extra problem, you are using `Dir.entries`, this in my OS gives regular entries more `.` and `..` which should be managed properly, they are not what you want to manipulate.

So, I wrote you a little script, I hope you find it readable, to me it works. You can improve it for sure! (p.s. I am under Linux OS).

```
# Global var only to stress its importance
$dir = "/home/p/tmp/t1"

Dir.chdir($dir)

# get list of files 
fnames = Dir.glob "*"

# get the max index "fileINDEX.txt" already used in the directory 
takenIndexes = []
fnames.each do |f|
  if f.match /^file(\d+).txt/ then takenIndexes.push $1.to_i; end 
end 

# get the first free index available 
firstFreeIndex = 1
firstFreeIndex = (takenIndexes.max + 1) if takenIndexes.length > 0 

# get a range of fresh indexes for possible use 
idxs = firstFreeIndex..(firstFreeIndex + (fnames.length))
# i transform the range to list and reverse the order because i want 
# to use "pop" to get and remove them.
idxs = idxs.to_a
idxs.reverse! 

# rename the files needing to be renamed
puts "--- Renamed files ----"
fnames.each do |f|
  # if file has already the wanted format then move to next iteration
  next if f.match /^file\d+.txt/
  newName = "file" + idxs.pop.to_s + ".txt"
  puts "rename: #{f} ---> #{newName}"
  File.rename(f, newName)
end
```